# react-router v3: How to load data for the component when the same route with different query params is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Using react-router v3, I can navigate for example to `/users?id=1`, and display the `UserDetails` component.

Now suppose that in that component I have a link to `/users?id=2`, to display another user.

The URL is effectively switched from `/users?id=1` to `/users?id=2`.

The problem is that I have some code in `componentWillMount()` of the `UserDetails` component that I would like to run for each user. But that code runs only the first time. It never runs a second time because the `UserDetails` component is already mounted.

Is there a way to force the `UserDetails` component to be completely reloaded (to run `componentWillMount`) when I click on the second user link ?

Comment: Or maybe should I use a different lifecycle method ?

Comment: Is it possible to see your code and the parent component where you have used this component and whether this component is a smart or dumb component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the component with the same route is called, its not remounted, However its props change and hence the `componentWillReceiveProps` function is called.

When using `react-router v3` , you could get the query params from `this.props.location.query`, so you would implement it like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.location.query.id !== this.props.location.query.id) {
        // do what you want to do with nextProps.location.query.id here
    }
}
```

Also instead of using query params, you could go with routes having `pathParams` like `/users/:id`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that one.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working with this, thanks :

```
class VerseList extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { fetchVerses } = this.props // from the store, bound to dispatch
    const { book, chapter } = this.props.params
    fetchVerses(book, chapter) // when done, will set isLoading(boolean) and verses[] in the store
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    const bookNew = newProps.params.book
    const chapterNew = newProps.params.chapter
    const { book, chapter } = this.props.params

    if ((bookNew !== book) || (chapterNew !== chapter)) {
      const { fetchVerses } = this.props
      fetchVerses(bookNew, chapterNew)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, verses } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="verse-list">
        {
          (isLoading === undefined || isLoading === true) ?
            <span>Loading</span> :
            verses.map(verse => (
              <Verse
                key={verse.number}
                number={verse.number}
                text={verse.text}
              />
            ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing your own answer using the same approach that other answer mentions, you could have just accepted his answer

Comment: Sorry, I am not used to the system. I was not writting an anwser, but just giving a comment. This comment editor is not good to display code I think, that is why I choosed to "answer"

Comment: If you noticed, I said thanks, not to myself obviously.